How to set up Control Flow Guard function calls for proper decompilation with Ghidra?
Say, I have the following x64 assembly code that runs on Windows:
MOV        EDX ,dword ptr [RSI ]                    ; 2nd param
TEST       EDX ,EDX
JZ         lbl_out_1                                ; Skip the call below if 2nd param is 0

MOV        RAX ,qword ptr [RBX ]                    ; Address of vtable in a class
XOR        R8D ,R8D                                 ; 3rd param (always 0)
MOV        RCX ,RBX                                 ; 1st param
MOV        RAX ,qword ptr [RAX  + 0x28 ]            ; address of a virtual function, or a later  JMP rax inside CFG shim
CALL       qword ptr [->_guard_dispatch_icall ]     ; CFG shim

lbl_out_1:

it invokes a virtual function, but before doing so it passes it through the Control Flow Guard (CFG) shim, or _guard_dispatch_icall.
The source code for the code above is invoking a (virtual) function in a class, at index 5 (because of the RAX  + 0x28 part), with the class pointer being in RBX.
I'm trying to make it more readable in the Ghidra's C-decompiler, but it looks like the CFG shim is messing it up. Here's what I did:
I created a custom Struct in Ghidra, let's call it MyClass, and set up a member at its offset 0x28, as my custom function, let's call it MyFunc.
MyFunc was defined as such:
NTSTATUS MyFunc(MyClass * this, DWORD wnf_paraM1, bool bUpdateUI)


And even though it made the Assembly code above more readable, the call through the CFG shim still wasn't showing the function parameters:
if ((pVars->paraM1 == 0) ||
   (lVar9 = (*(pMyClass)->
              MyFunc)(), -1 < lVar9)) goto LAB_18001be80;

Any idea how to make it work with the CFG shims?
